# How to remove an element from array and decrease the rank using LODASH

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am working in Angular2.
I have an array like below:

```
rank   |   book name
---------------------
  1    |   maths
  2    |   physics
  3    |   english
  4    |   hindi
```

Now i want to remove an Item, Let i am removing rank **1** and book name is **maths**

Which must be remove the maths row and adjust the ranks after that element.
I want the result will be like this:

```
rank   |   book name
---------------------
  1    |   physics
  2    |   english
  3    |   hindi
```

What to do Remove and also decrease the rank simultaneously using lodash in angular2?

Comment: 1. You don't need lodash for this. 2. Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without lodash

```
var array = ["Maths", "Physics", "English", "Hindi"];
const result = array.filter(array => array !== "Maths");
var object = {};
var i = 0;
for (rank in result) {
i++
object[i] = result[rank]
}
console.log(object);
```